# How to set conditional rendering navlink

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

i have two value at dataindex: isOnline (true and false) , this time my render NavLink on both true and false , but i want only render on false value not with true value. Is there any possibility to do that.

```
    {
        title:'On-Line / Off-Line',
        dataIndex: 'isOnline',
        render: (isOnline, row) => 
                <NavLink to={`${routePaths.LEADSFORM}/${row._id}`}> 
                       {isOnline}
                </NavLink>,
    }
```

Comment: in Render you can write a ternary to return null if isOnline is true.
something like 
<>
{
!isOnline ? your jsx : null
}
</>

Comment: can you please give me some sandbox demo....

Answer (score 0):

Try this link https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html:

```
{
    title:'On-Line / Off-Line',
    dataIndex: 'isOnline',
    render: (isOnline, row) => {
            if(!isOnline){
            <NavLink to={`${routePaths.LEADSFORM}/${row._id}`}> 
                   {isOnline}
            </NavLink>
          }
     }
}
```